# Distribution of a random vector

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Distribution of a random vector is given by the following table:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|} 
Y/X & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ \hline
1 & k & 2k & 7k & k \\ \hline
2 & 2k & 5k  & 6k & k\\ \hline
3 & k & 3k & 2k & k \\ 
\end{array}$$

Where k is some number. I am supposed to find k and also to find the probability that $X>Y$ and the probability of $Y>X$.

I have found that $k=1/32$, but I am not sure how to find the needed probabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability that $X > Y$ can be found by adding up probabilities:

$$P(X > Y) = P(X=2, Y=1) + P(X=3, Y=1) + \cdots$$

where you sum over all combinations of values of $X$ and $Y$ where $X > Y$.

Comment: right, it's totally simple. thanks